# Create schema with current date in name

Tags: sql, postgresql

I'm trying to create a new schema with todays date in the name. Named like this

```
select concat('Copy_', replace(now()::date::text,'-',''))
Copy_20181102
```

So I try:

```
CREATE SCHEMA concat('Copy_', replace(now()::date::text,'-',''))
    AUTHORIZATION postgres;
```

> ERROR: syntax error at or near "(" LINE 1: CREATE SCHEMA
>   concat('Copy_', replace(now()::date::text,'-',... ^ SQL state: 42601
>   Character: 21

How can I fix this?

Comment: `replace(now()::date::text,'-','')` is better written as `to_char(now(), 'yyyymmdd')` or `to_char(current_date, 'yyyymmdd')`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot do that with pure SQL. You need to use procedural language instead:

```
--Anonymous block
DO $$
BEGIN

    EXECUTE format('CREATE SCHEMA %I AUTHORIZATION postgres',
            concat('Copy_', replace(now()::date::text,'-','')));

END $$;
```

More info about dynamic commands [here](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/plpgsql-statements.html#PLPGSQL-STATEMENTS-EXECUTING-DYN).

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `\gexec` functionality of psql, which will execute the output of the given query. Let's note that the query can return multiple rows, leading to multiple sql instructions.

```
SELECT format('CREATE SCHEMA %I AUTHORIZATION postgres',
       concat('Copy_', replace(now()::date::text,'-','')));\gexec
```